# What would be the time complexity and space complexity of brute force approach of matrix chain multiplication?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, matrix-multiplication, space-complexity

I know the time complexity and space complexity of `matrix chain multiplication` using dynamic programming would be O(n^3) and O(n^2).

But I want to know the time as well as space complexity of the brute force approach for this problem which can be implemented with below code.

```
def MatrixChainOrder(p, i, j):
 
    if i == j:
        return 0
 
    _min = sys.maxsize
 
    for k in range(i, j):
 
        count = (MatrixChainOrder(p, i, k)
                 + MatrixChainOrder(p, k + 1, j)
                 + p[i-1] * p[k] * p[j])
 
        if count < _min:
            _min = count
 
    # Return minimum count
    return _min

#arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3]
#n = len(arr)
# p is array name
# i=1
#j= n-1
```

Please elaborate...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Are you asking about the complexity of [matrix chain multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication) using a dynamic programming algorithm (and if so, which algorithm exactly?), or the complexity of performing the actual multiplications? Big-O complexities are generally used as properties of _algorithms_, not _problems_. Without a clear description of - or reference to - the algorithm in question, it will be hard to make precise statements.

Comment: really sorry for that by mistake i forgot to mention more information, now I have updated my post

Answer (score 3):

The stack depth is linear, hence so is the space usage.

As for time, we get a recurrence

```
T(1) = 1
T(n) = sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (T(k) + T(n-k)) = 2 sum_{k=1}^{n-1} T(k).
```

We can verify that the solution is

```
T(1) = 1
T(n) = 2 (3^(n-1))
```

so the running time is Θ(3<sup>n</sup>).